# Can static functions and non-virtual methods be overridden? What is Static Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, polymorphism, virtual

Please see the output of this function function . It shows static functions can be overridden because derived class inherits function:

```
void put(){printf("Static functions in base class");}
```

if we dont override `put()` output is Static functions in base class
but we override it to be:

```
void put(){printf("Static functions are overridden in derived class");}
```

So output is Static functions are overridden in derived class
public:

```
#include<iostream>

class base{
public:
static void put(){printf("Static functions in base class");}
};

class derived : public base{
void put(){printf("Static functions are overridden in derived 
class");}    
};

int main(){
derived *bp = new derived;// Static Polymorphism //
bp->put();
return 0;
}
```

Since here `put()` is not a virtual function . SO can we override functions which are not virtual ?

Is it a case of static polymorphism ?

Comment: I dont see the polymorphism here. If you do `base* bp = new derived; bp->put();` it will call `base::put()` (i.e. no polymorphism). And please fix the errors in the code, as it is it wont compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can static functions be overridden?

No.

```
struct Base { static void f() {} };
struct Derived : Base { void f() {} };
```

`Base::f` and `Derived::f` are two distinct functions who don't even share a common interface: the proper takes no argument, the later an hidden pointer to a `Derived`.

> Can non virtual functions be overridden?

No.

```
struct Base { void f() {} };
struct Derived : Base { void f() {} };
```

`Derived::f` hides `Base::f` when you manipulate an object, a reference to an object or a pointer to an object of type `Derived`:

```
Derived d;
Derived& dref = d;
Derived* dptr = &d;
d.f(); // calls Derived::f
dref.f(); // calls Derived::f
dptr->f(); // calls Derived::f

Base& bref = d;
Base* bptr = &d;
bref.f(); // calls Base::f
bptr ->f(); // calls Base::f
```

Comment: .Sir what is den the difference between hiding the function inherited from base class and overriding the function inherited from base class?

Comment: @VinayakSangar In the second case, if `Base::f` (and thus `Derived::f`) was `virtual`, `bref.f()` and `bptr->f()` would call `Derived::f`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a case of static polymorphism: there is no "override" here, because the function invocation is completely resolved at compile time.

The compiler knows that `bp`'s type is `derived*`, so it invokes the static member function `derived::put`. Had the compile-time type of `bp` been `base*`, `base::put` would have been invoked - [demo](http://ideone.com/Vx7ndQ):

```
base *bp = new derived;
bp->put(); // prints "Static functions in base class"
```

That is why invoking static functions through instance pointers is misleading. The call in your code is equivalent to `derived::put()`, but the readers of your code must trace the type to the declaration in order to see that.

Answer (score 1):

No. Neither static member function, nor non virtual member function could be overrided.

For you case, if you change the type of `bp` to `base*`, you'll see the result will be

```
Static functions in base class
```

The static member function could not be overrided, they behavior like free function, doesn't depend on object, doesn't use `this` pointer implicitly. Which function will be called is determined by the static type.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang)